# Joining two tables with comma separated string id in one table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is branch detail table which have the `branch name` and the `employee id` work on that branch.

```
CREATE TABLE Branch_detail
   (`nid` int,`branch` varchar(15), `emp_with_department` varchar(15));

INSERT INTO Branch_detail
   (`nid`,`branch`, `emp_with_department`)
VALUES
  (1,'Mumbai', '1,2,4'),
  (2,'Banglore', '4,5');




 | nid |   branch | emp_with_department |
 |-----|----------|---------------------|
 |   1 |   Mumbai |               1,2,4 |  
 |   2 | Banglore |                 4,5 |
```

---

This is employee detail table with their respective designations.

```
CREATE TABLE Emp 
 (`id` int, `name` varchar(10), `Designations ` varchar(10));

INSERT INTO Emp 
 (`id`, `name`,`Designations `)
VALUES
 (1,'Rantesh', 'Executive'),
 (2,'Keith', 'Art'),
 (3,'Nikhil', 'Executive'),
 (4,'Gauresh', 'Art'),
 (5,'Sumit', 'Executive');


| id |    name | Designations |
|----|---------|--------------|
|  1 | Rantesh |  Executive   |
|  2 |   Keith |        Art   |
|  3 |  Nikhil |  Executive   |
|  4 | Gauresh |        Art   |
|  5 |   Sumit |  Executive   |
```

---

This query i tried to get atleast which id is Executive or Art employee

```
  SELECT  a.nid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.Designations ORDER BY b.id) Designations_Name
  FROM    Branch_detail a INNER JOIN Emp b
  ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.emp_with_department) > 0
  GROUP   BY a.nid


| nid |  Designations_Name|
|-----|-------------------|
|   1 | Executive,Art,Art |
|   2 |     Art,Executive |
```

Output should be:

count of Executives for nid=1,

count of Art for nid=1,

count of executives for nid=2,

count of Art for nid=1

OR

```
| nid |  count(Designations_Name)|
|-----|--------------------------|
|   1 | 1,2,2                    |
|   2 | 1,1                      |
```

I want the Output like there on `n` location, how many executive and art employee is present in count ?

this is sqlfiddle where the demo is present
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27aa51/1

Comment: Do not store foreign keys in this form. Learn about normalization

Comment: @ratnesh: although you should look at normalization, as suggested by Jens. Still, I have give a solution for your specific requirement. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51703975/2469308

Comment: i know normalization actually i have running project so i need to used some temporary solution. that's why i need query for that - @Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should implement [Normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html).

But still, here is a query which will work for you, utilizing [Nested Queries](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-queries-sql/):

```
select inner_nest.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(designations_count) 
FROM (SELECT a.nid, b.Designations, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) as designations_count 
      FROM Branch_detail a 
      INNER JOIN Emp b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.emp_with_department) > 0 
      WHERE 1 = 1 
      GROUP BY a.nid, b.Designations ) AS inner_nest 
GROUP BY inner_nest.nid
```

It gets Count for Art first, then Executives (as alphabetically Art comes first)

Comment: It Works Thank you @Madhur